# document.ready and window.load not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run some jQuery on a page which is getting content pulled in dynamically and creating links but can't get it to work. My code is simple:

```
$(".link a[href*='xyz'][href$='pdf']").text('change link text');
```

I have put this inside document.ready and window.load and neither made a difference. I've also ran it on the console in inspector and it works fine but on the live page it doesn't have any affect. I added a console.log to my code and I can see that the code is being triggered but can't figure out how to make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: How would this be implemented in my particular case?

Answer (score 2):

You need [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), Here in snippet I have used `setTimeout` to simulate anchor added dynamically.

```js
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var element = document.querySelector('.link');
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".link").append('<a class="myLink" href=".pdf">Yahoooooo</a>');
  $(".link").append('<a class="myLink" href=".xyz">Yahoooooo</a>');
}, 5000)

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type == "childList") {
      console.log("Nodes inserted changed")
      $(".link a[href$='pdf'], .link a[href*='xyz']").text('change link text');
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(element, {
  childList: true //configure it to listen to attribute changes
});
```

```css
.myLink {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link"></div>
```

Comment: We are both on the same route, but both not 100% correct. What if he has multiple tags with the .link class?

Comment: Thanks - this looks like it will do the trick. Is it just the following I need to remove for it to work in my case?    'var element = document.querySelector('.link');
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".link").append('<a class="myLink" href=".pdf">Yahoooooo</a>');
  $(".link").append('<a class="myLink" href=".xyz">Yahoooooo</a>');
}, 5000)'

Comment: @podusmonens, You need to remove `setTimeout(....)` portion keep `var element = document.querySelector('.link');`

Comment: W. Scott, there are multiple links on the page with the same class that I need to change all at once.

Comment: Afraid this doesn't work. I'm getting the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.'

Comment: @podusmonens what are you passing as argument, share you code

Comment: var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var element = document.querySelector('.link');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type == "childList") {
      console.log("Nodes inserted changed")
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(element, {
  childList: true //configure it to listen to attribute changes
});

Comment: Oops, can't figure out how to format code in a reply. Just tried the above without actually making a change, just waiting for it to exist but it returns the same error.

Comment: @podusmonens, You need to pass a parent element selector which exists initally on the document. `document.querySelector('selectorForElementWhichExistsInitially')`

Comment: @Satpal Still doesn't work, does it matter if it's inside document.ready or window.load?

Comment: @podusmonens yes it does matter

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some type of [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) as described by Satpal.

However, JQuery can help you with this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".link").append('<a class="myLink" href=".pdf"></a>');
        $(".link").append('<a class="myLink" href=".xyz"></a>');
    });

    $(".link").bind("DOMNodeInserted", function(){
        $(".link a[href$='pdf'], .link a[href*='xyz']").text('change link text');
    });
});
```

```css
.myLink {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link"></div>

<button>Click Me</button>
```

Also, I had to adjust your CSS selector for the links.

Comment: `DOMNodeInserted` is not MutationObserver

Comment: Satpal, You are correct. It was not until you said something that I realized DOMNodeInserted is depreciated. I'll update my answer.